# How to take a user input of 24 hour time in HHMM format? (without importing any modules)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to accept a user input for time, between 0000 and 2359, without importing any modules.
I currently have it just taking an int input:

```
fillTime = "X"
while fillTime == "X":
    try:
        fillTime = int(input("Enter the time (0000-2359): "))
        if fillTime < 0 or fillTime > 2359:
                print("Error! Please enter a valid time!")
                fillTime = "X"
        else:
            break
    except:
        print("An unknown error occurred!")
```

however this doesn't verify if the time is invalid (e.g. 1299 etc.) Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit** fixed an error in my code, first line was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the modulo operator to verify the last two digits. Also your loop should not check for "X". Just use `while True` and `break`:

```
while True:
    try:
        fillTime = int(input("Enter the time (0000-2359): "))
        if not (0 <= fillTime <= 2359) or fillTime % 100 > 59:
            print("Error! Please enter a valid time!")
        else:
            break
    except:
        print("An unknown error occurred!")
```